# Can I make Google Analytics set its cookies on just a subdomain? (I.e. www.example.com, not example.com)

Tags: google-analytics

I’m using Google Analytics on a site — let’s call it `www.example.com`.

My Google Analytics website profile is for`www.example.com`, and my only report is set up for `www.example.com`. Requests to `example.com` redirect permanently to `www.example.com`.

I’ve got the regular Analytics JavaScript on my index page for the domain. For some reason, it seems to be setting its cookies for `example.com` instead of `www.example.com`.

This is unfortunate, as I’ve got `cdn.example.com` set up as a CDN using Amazon Cloudfront, so I’d rather not have useless cookies (Analytics seems to set four cookies) cluttering up those requests.

How can I make Analytics set cookies for `www.example.com` instead of `example.com`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the way to achieve this is to add the following line to your Analytics JavaScript, with the other `_gaq.push` calls:

```
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'www.example.com']);
```

(See http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingSite.html#siteLinkingConsiderations)

That fixed the cookies for me.

Comment: @stevelove: you’re most welcome!